# No subnet6 declaration for eth0

Tags: dhcp-server

I keep getting this error in my syslog when I try to start a dhcp6 server.
The command I use is.

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
```

The error I get is:

```
No subnet6 declaration for eth0 (fd30::1:ff4e:3e:0:2c).
```

My ifconfig is:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.115.43  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 192.168.115.255
        inet6 fd30::1:ff4e:3e:0:d  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fd30::1:400b:3ffd:a32e:6c3c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::3b1f:660f:3760:5894  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd30::1:ff4e:3e:0:2c  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether b8:27:eb:24:3a:85  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7890  bytes 665917 (650.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1571  bytes 596641 (582.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And My dhcpd6.conf is as follows.

```
default-lease-time 144000;
max-lease-time 129600;
ddns-updates on;
ddns-update-style none;
log-facility local7;

option space docsis code width 2 length width 2 hash size 17;
option docsis.tftp-servers code 32 = array of ip6-address;
option docsis.cablelabs-configuration-file code 33 = text;
option docsis.cablelabs-syslog-servers code 34 = array of ip6-address;
option docsis.device-id code 36 = string;
option docsis.time-servers code 37 = array of ip6-address;
option docsis.time-offset code 38 = signed integer 32;
option vsio.docsis code 4491 = encapsulate docsis;
option docsis.cablelabs-syslog-servers fd30::1:ff4e:3e:0:d;

option docsis.time-servers fd30::1:ff4e:3e:0:34;
option docsis.time-offset 28800;


option dhcp6.rapid-commit;
authorative;
allow booting;


subnet6 fd30::1:ff4e:3e:0:c/128 {
     deny unknown-clients;
}


subnet6 fd00:2222:2222:2226::/64 {
    range6 fd00:2222:2222:2226::2 fd00:2222:2222:2226::ff;
  #config filename
   option docsis.tftp-servers fd30::1:ff4e:3e:0:34;
   option docsis.cablelabs-configuration-file "BPI_CM3_1.bin";
}


subnet6 fd00:2222:2222:2227::/64 {
    range6 fd00:2222:2222:2227::2 fd00:2222:2222:2227::ff;
}
```

Comment: is it possibly a typo? you have fd30::1:ff4e:3e:0:2c/128, but in the config fd30::1:ff4e:3e:0:c/128 (missing a '2' before the 'c')

Comment: Your ULA addressing does not look like you used a random number generator for the 40-bit Global ID, which is a requirement. `30:0000:0000` looks unlikely to be randomly chosen.

Answer (score 0):

```
inet6 fd30::1:400b:3ffd:a32e:6c3c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
```

You have an ip in the `fd30:0:0:1::/64` subnet assigned to the interface and you don't seem to have a subnet6 for that `/64`